# S3 Bucket Policy to Allow access to specific users and restrict all

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I searched through existing questions and couldnt find an answer. Hence posting here.

I want to restrict access to a S3 bucket to all users except select few users using S3 Bucket policy. I understand IAM policy is easy to manage and administer, i dont like to create roles and groups for this specific case and want S3 bucket policy created.

Here is what i have tried so far and it is not restricting access to users as expected.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "bucketPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {

      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/allowedusername"]
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    },
    {

      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/denieduser"]
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }

  ]
}
```

I tried to deny all like below but that explicit deny took precedence over allow and i myself am not able to access the bucket now ;-( Thats another issue i have

```
{

          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": ["*"]
          },
          "Action": "s3:*",
          "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",
                       "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
        }
```

Answer (score 10):

To achieve what you want, use an explicit deny with a `NotPrincipal` policy element. The policy below will ensure no other user can access the buckets other than the users listed in the `NotPrincipal` element:

```
{
        "Id": "bucketPolicy",
        "Statement": [
                {
                        "Action": "s3:*",
                        "Effect": "Deny",
                        "NotPrincipal": {
                                "AWS": [
                                        "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/alloweduser"
                                ]
                        },
                        "Resource": [
                                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",
                                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: ```This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Id For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies.```

Comment: @excessivedemon What if any AWS service wants to access this bucket? i.e EMR or redshift.

Comment: Same question as @ImPurshu , what if in the same time we want other services to access the bucket ?

Comment: where do we add the above policy?  you can't add principal policies in the Policies section, or attached to users.  Do you add it to the bucket?  if so, how?