# Kinesis Firehose and S3 bucket protected by IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to create a Kinesis Firehose stream (on AWS) that write in a S3 bucket with a restricted bucket policy.

```
My bucket policy :

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAllExcept",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myrestrictedbucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::myrestrictedbucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEqualsIfExists": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-1234567"
                },
                "NotIpAddressIfExists": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "xx.xx.xx.xx/32",
                        "52.19.239.192/27"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note : 52.19.239.192/27 are the IP addresses for EU (Ireland) (found in the documentation for accessing a Redshift cluster).

For now, it doesn't work and I have this error :
*Access was denied. Ensure that the trust policy for the provided IAM role allows Firehose to assume the role, and the access policy allows access to the S3 bucket.*

If I disable my bucket policy, it works perfectly.

Does anyone know how to add a specific condition that would let Firehose write in my S3 bucket ?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Damien

Comment: have you instead tried to limit the access to `"Principal": {"Service": "firehose.amazonaws.com"}` instead?

Comment: The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207399/s3-bucket-policy-to-allow-access-to-specific-users-and-restrict-all?rq=1 covers this scenario.